# Loop variable IDW gstat R

Tags: r, gstat

Is there a way to loop over variables inside an SpatialPointsDataFrame object in R using IDW interpolation of gstat package ?

I mean something like this

```
for (day in list_days) {
  P.idw <- gstat::idw(day~1, P, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)
  r       <- raster(P.idw)
  plot(r)
}
```

Edit:
Because that structure gives me error:

```
Error in predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  : 
  too many spatial dimensions: 58
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.gstat(g, newdata = newdata, block = block, nsim = nsim,  :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

But if I write directly the name of the variable it works fine:

```
P.idw <- gstat::idw(X2018.01.14~1, P, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)
```

Comment: Try with `P.idw <- gstat::idw(get(day)~1, P, newdata=grd, idp=2.0)`

Comment: Perfect " it works !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `day~1` you can do `as.formula(paste(day, "~ 1"))`